# После редиректа слетают таблицы стилей

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с "человеческими" ссылками.
К примеру, нужно, чтобы на страницу http://mysite.ru/index.php?option=tag&t=vaz можно было попасть вписав в адресную строку http://mysite.ru/tag/vaz

Вот содержимое файла .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/?$ ?option=tag&t=$1
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

на нужную страницу вроде переходит, но почему-то слетают таблицы стилей.
Сайт на денвере.

Comment: Здравствуйте! У меня похожая проблема. На локальном сервере прописал абсолютный пусть к файлу стилей и вроде все работает. Но когда нажимаю обновить страницу, стили слетают. После того как залил сайт на хостинг ничего не изменилось, все работает до момента обновления страницы. Подскажите, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у Вас есть другие вопросы, Вы можете задать их нажав кнопку "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Дополнительно Вы можете [добавить вознаграждение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда Ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет достаточного уровня.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(*.)/(*.)/?$ ?option=$1&t=$2
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

по поводу стилей, проверьте подключение файлов скорей всего у вас указан относительный путь, надо исправить на абсолютный, например:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> //относительный
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css"> //абсолютный от корня сайта
```

Comment: Точно, всё работает. Благодарю!